Tensor product of Brauer algebra modules
Let $V,W$ be two modules for the Brauer algebra $B_n(\delta)$.
Is it known in general how one can regard $V\otimes W$ as a module for the Brauer algebra? That is, is there any analog of a Hopf structure $\Delta: B_n(\delta) \rightarrow B_n(\delta)\otimes B_n(\delta)$? Or is there any algebra $A$ with an algebra map $\Delta: B_n(\delta)\to B_n(\delta)\otimes A $ that would allow me to have a structure of Brauer algebra modules on $V\otimes W$ for an $A$-module $W$ and $B_n(\delta)$-module $V$?
I have tried to look for this information in the web, but I couldn't find.

Although the Hecke algebra has no coproduct, Berenstein and Kazhdan defined a Hecke-Hopf algebra that contains the Hecke algebra as a coideal subalgebra and does have a coproduct, very much like you'd like: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02076. The definition is quite natural if one thinks of de Hecke action by Demazure–Lusztig operators  on polynomials. Perhaps one can similarly define a "Brauer-Hopf algebra".
